# If I have comma seperated values in a column , to use it in where condition I have used split_part. But it is taking more time in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, split

In PostgreSQL, I have a column receipt_id which will have comma separated values or a single value .
Eg:

[image]

I need to use the values in the third column with another table called Voucher in where condition .

I have used split_part.

```
select  ap.document_no AS invoice_number,
    ap.curr_date AS invoice_date,ap.receipt_id,split_part(ap.receipt_id::text, ','::text, 1),
    split_part(ap.receipt_id::text, ','::text, 2)
    from ap_invoice_creation ap , voucher v 
    where  (v.voucher_id::text IN      
           ( SELECT split_part(ap_invoice_creation.receipt_id::text, ','::text, 1) AS parts
           FROM ap_invoice_creation
          WHERE ap_invoice_creation.receipt_id::text = ap.receipt_id::text
        UNION
         SELECT split_part(ap_invoice_creation.receipt_id::text, ','::text, 2) AS parts
           FROM ap_invoice_creation
          WHERE ap_invoice_creation.receipt_id::text = ap.receipt_id::text
        UNION
         SELECT split_part(ap_invoice_creation.receipt_id::text, ','::text, 3) AS parts
           FROM ap_invoice_creation
          WHERE ap_invoice_creation.receipt_id::text = ap.receipt_id::text)) AND ap.status::text = 'Posted'::text
```

But this is a part of query, it is taking more time.
Because of this entire query is taking more time.

Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should not even be storing CSV like this.  That being said, there is no need for `SPLIT_PART()` here and big ugly union.  Consider this version:

```sql
SELECT
    ap.document_no AS invoice_number,
    ap.curr_date AS invoice_date,
    ap.receipt_id,
    SPLIT_PART(ap.receipt_id::text, ',', 1),
    SPLIT_PART(ap.receipt_id::text, ',', 2)
FROM ap_invoice_creation ap
INNER JOIN voucher v 
    ON ',' || ap.receipt_id || ',' LIKE '%,' || v.voucher_id::text || ',%';
```

Comment: Thank you . It returned the exact number of records.

Comment: `... ON ap.receipt_id = any(string_to_array(v.voucher_id, ',')` would be more robust. But the JOIN is doing something different than the original IN condition.

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve performance would be to get rid of the dreaded CSV value, and store the data in a proper one-to-many relationship.

If you can't do that, you can use an EXISTS condition rather than a cross join with an IN condition that uses three queries:

```
select ap.document_no AS invoice_number,
       ap.curr_date AS invoice_date,
       ap.receipt_id,
       split_part(ap.receipt_id, ',', 1),
       split_part(ap.receipt_id, ',', 2)
from ap_invoice_creation ap 
WHERE EXISTS (select *
              from voucher v
              where v.voucher_id = any (string_to_array(ap.receipt_id, ',')))
WHERE ap.status = 'Posted'
```

Comment: Note that the JOIN in Tim's answer returns a different result than your IN condition.

Comment: Yes , I don't need inner join . I will use left join . It is working fine.

Comment: SELECT
    ap.document_no AS invoice_number,
    ap.curr_date AS invoice_date,
    ap.receipt_id,
    SPLIT_PART(ap.receipt_id::text, ',', 1),
    SPLIT_PART(ap.receipt_id::text, ',', 2)
FROM ap_invoice_creation ap
LEFT JOIN voucher v 
    ON ',' || ap.receipt_id || ',' LIKE '%,' || v.voucher_id::text || ',%';   

This one and  your query gives the same output and it is correct.

Comment: @Dharani.C: well, the join will return each row from ap_invoice_creation multiple times if there are multiple values in `receipt_id`. The EXISTS condition will not. https://dbfiddle.uk/r5kQMLij

Comment: Thanks for the information. Repeated records is fine . So join is fine in my case.